# Processing csv file then send result by email

Tags: node.js, csv, asynchronous, graphql, papaparse

I have page where the user can upload large csv file of sku's, then in the backend I do some processing of these sku's and then send email of the results, my question is:
do I need some kind of queuing in my backend like Bull ? or I can achieve that without queuing or jobs pooling ?

my code :

```
  let url = "https://my-csv.file-url";
  let data: any[] = []
  data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const parseStream = Papa.parse(Papa.NODE_STREAM_INPUT, {});
    const dataStream = request
        .get(url)
        .pipe(parseStream);

    parseStream.on("data", (chunk: any) => {
        data.push(chunk);
        //checking and processing of the csv file

    });

    dataStream.on("finish", () => {
        //send email to the user of the result
    });
});
```

Comment: ... and you checked it? is it a working code? where is the problem? timeouts? costly processing? how it is graphql related?

Comment: @xadm thank you for the reply, its working but I guess when uploading 60k records, which i didn't test, I need some kind of queuing solution, not sure what is the best way to achieve that, for the graphql, this function is inside resolver, I didn't put that :)

Comment: I guess you should test it ... if fails/timeouts (change limits?) then [I guess] no parsing during fetching ... fetch all the file to temp location, and use some queue processing.